# How to pass variables in RTL YAML files for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, translation, right-to-left

I have a en.yml file segment like this:

```
email_subject: "A user has referred %{community}"
```

In ar.yml (Arabic) I have used Google Translate to translate the segment like this:

```
email_subject: "المستخدم المشار%{community}المجتمع"
```

(The translation may be wrong. Sorry I don't know Arabic)

When working with yaml files for left-to-right languages (especially for Ruby on Rails), my questions are below:

1. The "email_subject: " part should remain same as en.yml (LTR), right?
2. for the Arabic text inside "", they should be in LTR or RTL?
3. For the **%{community}** variable, should it be LTR or RTL (in other words, should it be **yyyy}tinummoc{%xxx** ?
4. How to insert the **%{community}** variable inside the Arabic text while typing in Sublime Text or a similar text editor?

Answer (score 1):

lets assume your yml file looks like this:

```
 ar:
  models:
    email_subject: "المستخدم المشار%{community}المجتمع"
```

then you will insert the community variable like this in the translation:

```
I18n.t('models.email_subject', community: 'عربي')
```

you should not care about if the community variable is RTL or LTR since as far as I18n is concerned is to provide the appropriate translation for the given language, so the rendering direction should be handled in your front end css code depending on the language chosen by the user.

also note you should add spaces in your translation around the variable since I18n will not add them for you like this:

```
email_subject: "المستخدم المشار %{community} المجتمع"
```

Comment: Thanks @Abdullah Fadhel. 
1. Do you mean the text behind "email_subject: " can be LTR or RTL and it won't matter? 2. What about the word %{community}? Does it needs to be LTR? 
3. We don't need space before and after %{community} right? What you said at the end is purely optional?
Note I am ONLY asking about the .yml file here. I don't care about the "translation" file.

Comment: yah the text behind "email_subject" can be LTR or RTL it does not matter. when they get rendered it is the responsibility of the CSS to render them in the appropriate direction. and that apply also to the `community` variable since after all it holds text  only.

Comment: @Freelensia yah the later section of the answer is optional as you said. however do not worry about the yml file as I told you. you just put the translated text and it provides the text depending on the locale if it is ar or en and does not car if it is RTL or LTR.

Comment: What about the %{community} word ? Do I have to write that in reverse (y-t-i-n-u-m-m-o-m) if the text is in RTF ?

Comment: what if this is being sent in a text message instead of rendered in a web page, how do we control the RTL vs LTR then?